# Calculate period length of recurring decimal fraction

Tags: python, python-3.6, fractions, recurring

I want to do a program in python (3.6.5) that tell the length of e.g. 1/7. The output should be for this example something like: "length: 6, repeated numbers: 142857". I got this so far:

```
n = int(input("numerator: "))
d = int(input("denominator: "))

def t(n, d):
    x = n * 9
    z = x
    k = 1
    while z % d:
        z = z * 10 + x
        k += 1
        print ("length:", k)
        print ("repeated numbers:", t)

    return k, z / d

t(n, d)
```

Comment: why are you multiplying n by 9?

Comment: What input should produce your example output? Its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I guess you want `str(1./7)` and find [the largest repeating substring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63329/finding-the-largest-repeating-substring) in it.

Comment: Apart from `print ("repeated numbers:", t)`, which I assume is a simple typo, your algorithm is fine, but there's no need to put those prints in the loop, and you should use `//` floor division instead of `/`. You should also handle leading zeroes. And you need to print the tuple returned by your function.

Comment: FYI: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-period-decimal-value-1n/ lacks a Python Implementation for that.

Comment: @PM2Ring sadly not the output is: "repeated numbers: <function t at 0x00000145CD1417B8>"

Comment: That's because `t` is your function object.

Comment: What about 1/6?

Comment: @Goyo Good point. ;) This algorithm gets stuck in a loop if the decimal contains any non-repeating part, that is, if the denominator has any factors of 2 or 5.

Comment: Stop close-voting as "unclear"; the question's self-evidently about recurring decimal fractions and is on-topic, even if not well-stated.

Comment: [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is often helpful in eliminating the manual digit manipulation, try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `print ("repeated numbers:", t)` prints the representation of the `t` function itself, not its output.

Here's a repaired version of your code. I use a Python 3.6+ f-string to convert the repeating digits to a string, and add zeros to the front to make it the correct length.

```
def find_period(n, d):
    z = x = n * 9
    k = 1
    while z % d:
        z = z * 10 + x
        k += 1

    digits = f"{z // d:0{k}}"
    return k, digits

# Test

num, den = 1, 7
period, digits = find_period(num, den)
print('num:', num, 'den:', den, 'period:', period, 'digits:', digits)

num, den = 1, 17
period, digits = find_period(num, den)
print('num:', num, 'den:', den, 'period:', period, 'digits:', digits)
```

**output**

```
num: 1 den: 7 period: 6 digits: 142857
num: 1 den: 17 period: 16 digits: 0588235294117647
```

---

This line may be a bit mysterious:

```
f"{z // d:0{k}}"
```

It says: Find the largest integer less than or equal to `z` divided by `d`, convert it to a string, and pad it on the left with zeroes (if necessary) to give it a length of `k`.

---

As  Goyo points out in the comments, this algorithm is not perfect. It gets stuck in a loop if the decimal contains any non-repeating part, that is, if the denominator has any factors of 2 or 5. See if you can figure out a way to deal with that.

Comment: I'm dealing with mixed recurring decimals, and I found a way to find the length of the non-recurring part. [code](https://gist.github.com/jack980517/e903cddfb9e0c6c59c82bcab2d009f28)

You could then multiply the number with `10^length_of_not_recurring_part` to get a pure recurring decimal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rewritten Python Implementation of https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-recurring-sequence-fraction/

```
def repeating_sequence_of_fraction(numerator, denominator):
    """ This function returns the repeating sequence of a fraction.
        If a repeating sequence doesn't exit, then returns an empty string """

    # Create a map to store already seen remainders
    # remainder is used as key and its position in
    # result is stored as value. Note that we need
    # position for cases like 1/6.  In this case,
    # the recurring sequence doesn't start from first
    # remainder.
    result = ""
    mapping = {}

    # Find first remainder
    remainder = numerator % denominator

    # Keep finding remainder until either remainder
    # becomes 0 or repeats
    while remainder != 0 and remainder not in mapping:

        # Store this remainder
        mapping[remainder] = len(result)

        remainder = remainder * 10

        # Append remainder / denominator to result
        #result_part = int(remainder / denominator)
        result_part = remainder // denominator
        result += str(result_part)
        # print(f"Result: {result}")

        # Update remainder
        remainder = remainder % denominator
        # print(f"Map: {mapping}")

    # Return result
    if (remainder == 0):
        return ""
    else:
        return result[mapping[remainder]:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #result = repeating_sequence_of_fraction(1, 3)
    #result = repeating_sequence_of_fraction(9, 11)
    #result = repeating_sequence_of_fraction(7, 12)
    result = repeating_sequence_of_fraction(1, 7)
    #result = repeating_sequence_of_fraction(1, 81)
    #result = repeating_sequence_of_fraction(5, 74)
    if result == "":
        print("No repeating sequence")
    else:
        print(f"\nLenght of repeating sequence: {len(result)}")
        print(f"\nRepeating sequence is {result}\n")
```

Comment: Have you tested it? it yields correct results for the few prime number denominators I've tested it on but otherwise it just returns incorrect results every time...

Comment: @loko Code updated. Now tested with the factions given in the code.