# Finding period of decimal 1/n fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52384356/12661230), I found a code that really work with some numbers. But it doesn't work with numbers like 15, 45, 6 or 14. How to make it work for those numbers ?

```
def find_period(n, d):
    z = x = n * 9
    k = 1
    while z % d:
        z = z * 10 + x
        k += 1

    digits = f"{z // d:0{k}}"
    return k, digits


# Test

num, den = 1, 7
period, digits = find_period(num, den)
print('num:', num, 'den:', den, 'period:', period, 'digits:', digits)

num, den = 1, 17
period, digits = find_period(num, den)
print('num:', num, 'den:', den, 'period:', period, 'digits:', digits)
```

Comment: 15 or 45 or 6 or 14: what do you mean ? Give an example where the code in the link  is not working ?

Comment: Do you mean `num, den = 1, 15` for example ?

Answer (score 0):

The code works but it is constantly looping. The problem is that the mathematical operation that is being performed is not letting the loop break.

For example, `num, den = 1, 7` the code `z % d` returns 0 after five iterations where condition of loop fails and return is executed.

But if we are using `num, den = 1, 15`, the code `z % d` never returns 0 because

```
9 % 15 = 9
99 % 15 = 9
999 % 15 = 9
```

and so on.

Similar case is with `num, den = 1, 45`, `num, den = 1, 14` and `num, den = 1, 6` where `z % d != 0`